# SQL, Layout for CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to make `i.ItemLookupCode, t.tostoreid, t.fromponumber, t.toloc_itemdescription, t.qtydifference` in there own columns. Currently when I run the script the data is all in one column.

Please see below for current script.

```
EXEC msdb. dbo .sp_send_dbmail @recipients= 'ME@ME.com' ,
@profile_name = 'mymailprofile' ,
@subject ='Quantity difference ' ,
@body ='Quantity difference ' ,

@query = '
(
  select i.ItemLookupCode, t.tostoreid, t.fromponumber, t.toloc_itemdescription, t.qtydifference
  from
  [RAMPApple] .[dbo]. [RAPurchaseOrderTransfer] t
  inner join [RAMPApple] .[dbo]. [RAItems] i on t.TOLOC_ItemDescription = i.ItemDescription
   where QtyDifference <> 0 and fromstoreid = 111 and t.DateCreated >= dateadd(dd, -30,  GETDATE()))
' ,
@query_result_header = 1,

@attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Quantity_difference.csv' ,
@query_result_separator = '     ' ,
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to build a CSV, then it seems to me that you need the separator character to be a comma, right?  Currently you're using some kind of whitespace as your separator and so the whole row appears to be a single column.

try using:

```
@query_result_separator = ',' ,
```

instead of

```
@query_result_separator = '     ' ,
```

Comment: @query_result_separator = ',' , just added , I had to use tab... Thank you